# Trouble getting Input Focus in JFrame(s)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, focus

Here's the (simplified) JPanel class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Preface extends JPanel{


  public Preface(){
    this.addKeyListener(new Controls());
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
    System.out.println(this.hasFocus());//false
    this.repaint();
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g); 

    g.drawImage(Tetris.getTexture("PrefacePoster.jpg"), 0, 0, 420, 556, null);
  }

}
```

I was having problems getting key events to work, and realized that my panels aren't getting the input focus to begin with, and thus not generating any KeyEvents.

I've tried grabFocus(), requestFocusInWindow(), requestFocus(), etc., yet hasFocus() always returns false.

Why aren't my JPanels gaining input focus? Is there some way I can force them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component is not focusable by default. So you need:

```
setFocusable( true );
```

in the constructor. The other methods `requestFocusInWindow()` only work on visible components on a visible JFrame. Invoking that method from the constructor will do nothing.

Same for the repaint() method. The component is not yet visible so there is no need for that statement in the constructor.

> not generating any KeyEvents.

You shouldn't be using a KeyListener to listen for KeyEvents. Instead you should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). `Key Bindings` will work even if the component doesn't have focus.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I moved the requestFocusInWindow() out of the constructor and added a call to setFocusable(). 

As far as Key Bindings go, I've actually already tried those to solve this same problem, yet had no luck. 

Thanks again.